# avoiding duplicates oracle aapex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i am trying to avoid duplicates in a table called 'incomingrequest', my table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE "REGISTRY"."INCOMINGREQUEST" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "FILENUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "REQUESTEDFILE" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
    "REQUESTEDDEPARTMENT" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "REQUESTDATE" DATE, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "URGENCY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "VOLUME" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "SUB" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "REGISTRYID" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "TEMPORARY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
   )
```

and the table data is a s follows

```
filenumber      Filename        requester           status     REQUESTEDDEPARTMENT
   1/11/2       Payments         JOSHUA MITCHELL    PENDING        DAY CARE
   1/11/2       Payments         JOSHUA MITCHELL    Delivered      DAY CARE
   1/11/2       Payments         JOSHUA MITCHELL    PENDING        DAY CARE
   1/11/2       Payments         RAWLE MUSGRAVE     PENDING        COMCORP
```

NB i only included the important fields above for this scenario (the other fields in the table has data).

What i want to achieve is ,when the app_user which in this case is the department (daycare) makes the same request while the previous request is pending(status) i want an error to occur. so the 3rd record/request should not have happen.

the trigger i am trying is

```
create or replace trigger "INCOMINGREQUEST_T1"
BEFORE
insert or update or delete on "INCOMINGREQUEST"
for each row

DECLARE counter INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO COUNTER FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(rownum) FROM INCOMINGREQUEST  WHERE requesteddepartment = V('APP_USER')
      and status ='PENDING');
    IF counter = 1 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20012,'Duplicated value');
    END IF;
END;
```

but i am getting an error

```
REGISTRY.INCOMINGREQUEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "REGISTRY.INCOMINGREQUEST_T1", line 3 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'REGISTRY.INCOMINGREQUEST_T1'
```

Comment: You have a trigger on table `INCOMINGREQUEST`. Inside the trigger you cannot select from this table `INCOMINGREQUEST`. There are many many questions here on SO with exactly the same problem, use the search function.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the desired behavior using the conditional `UNIQUE index` as following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INCOMINGREQUEST_IDX ON
    T1 ( CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING'   
              THEN FILENUMBER
         END );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: am sorry i made a mistake in my explanation, many people could request the same file at the same time which will have a pending status, however once the app_user is requesting the same file(maybe press the insert button twice by mistake) while it is pending to that app_user the will get a duplicated error

Answer (score 0):

You could use a procedure to stop duplicates, and pass over the parameters you need to insert into the table.

The issue with using a Trigger to find the current status is that you cannot query information from a table you are inserting/updating/deleting from inside the trigger as the data is "Mutating".

To run the procedure use:

BEGIN

stack_prc('DAY CARE', 'PENDING');

END;

[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKIVQ.png)